# How to manipulate where the cursor jumps when pressing tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

```js
var host;
var absender;
var pw;
var empf;
var sub;
var mess;





function sende() {

  host = document.getElementById("Host").value;
  absender = document.getElementById("ID").value;
  pw = document.getElementById("PW").value;
  empf = document.getElementById("AT").value;
  sub = document.getElementById("Subject").value;
  mess = document.getElementById("Message").value;


  Email.send({
    Host: host,
    Username: absender,
    Password: pw,
    To: empf,
    From: absender,
    Subject: sub,
    Body: mess
  });



  document.getElementById("AT").value = "";
  document.getElementById("Subject").value = "";
  document.getElementById("Message").value = "";

  alert("Email has been sent to " + empf);


}




function save() {

  localStorage.setItem("Host", host);
  localStorage.setItem("Absender", absender);
  localStorage.setItem("Passwort", pw);


}


function getData() {

  document.getElementById("Host").value = localStorage.getItem("Host");
  document.getElementById("ID").value = localStorage.getItem("Absender");
  document.getElementById("PW").value = localStorage.getItem("Passwort");

}


function deleter() {

  localStorage.removeItem("Host", host);
  localStorage.removeItem("Absender", absender);
  localStorage.removeItem("Passwort", pw);

}








function gib() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("PW").value);
}
```

```css
#UmAlles {
  width: 490px;
  height: 185px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

#containMess {
  width: 300px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  left: 190;
  top: 2;
}

#mess {
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#MailContainer {
  height: 168px;
  width: 190px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 163;
}

table {
  align-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

td {
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 30%;
  align-content: center;
}

tr {
  align-content: center;
}

.boxxes {
  width: 98%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  margin: 3px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
}

#Message {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #000;
}

.glow-on-hover {
  width: 220px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #111;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 220px;
  left: 230px;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.glow-on-hover:before {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #ff7300, #fffb00, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  background-size: 400%;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(5px);
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
  animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.glow-on-hover:active {
  color: #000
}

.glow-on-hover:active:after {
  background: transparent;
}

.glow-on-hover:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.glow-on-hover:after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #111;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes glowing {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 400% 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title> Mailer </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script> -->
  <script src="js/FileSaver.js"></script>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body onload="getData()">


  <div id="UmAlles">
    <form>
      <div id="containMess"><textarea id="Message" placeholder="Email-Inhalt" cols="35" rows="4" tabindex="5"></textarea></div>
      <div id="MailContainer">
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="Host" placeholder="Host-Server" class="boxxes" tabindex="0"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td><input type="text" id="ID" placeholder="Versender-Email" class="boxxes" tabindex="1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td><input type="password" id="PW" placeholder="Passwort" class="boxxes" tabindex="2"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td><input type="text" id="AT" placeholder="Empfänger" class="boxxes" tabindex="3"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td><input type="text" id="Subject" placeholder="Betreff" class="boxxes" tabindex="4"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <button class="glow-on-hover" type="button" onClick="sende()" tabindex="6">Send Email</button>

      <button type="button" onClick="save()" tabindex="7">Save Data</button>
      <button type="button" onClick="getData()" tabindex="8">Get Data</button>
      <button type="button" onClick="deleter()" tabindex="9">delete Data</button>

    </form>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Instruction: click a field, press tab continuously and watch its behavior.

Question: How to manipulate the tabbing properly, as in simply setting an order in which it works? (I know it normally just jumps in the order the elements are in the HTML file)

How to exclude anything outside the `<html>`?

I'm looking forward to any suggestions as I am just curious about the mechanics behind it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, if you want to just skip an element use `tabindex="-1"`

Comment: i would for example want to skip the elements outside the <html>... those in the browser head

Comment: well, outside of the `<html>` tag there is nothing, as it's the outer most tag and the `<head>` is not rendered at all in the browser page. BTW `tabindex="-1"` will make that element unreachable when hitting the *tab* key.

Comment: ok ... but I have tested and it seems some websites did manage it so that you cant use tab to jump out of the page into the browser head :/

Comment: OK now I understand your question, I gave you a possible answer using JS, but please update your question to better reflect your needs

Comment: Note that this will mess up a lot of people's workflow who use keyboard navigation for accessibility reasons.

Comment: BTW, this is about 10 times the amount of code needed to demonstrate the issue. Please read [mre] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

> After chatting in the comments, the real question is how to focus input elements with tab key and after the last element, loop back to the first input element without focusing the native browser UI (i.e. the back/forth arrow, the URL input, etc.)

There seems that the only option is with JS, you can listen for `keydown` event on the last input element and then focus the first input element.

```js
function focusFirst (e) {
  const keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode

  if (keyCode == 9) {
    // suppose that the first tabindex is 1
    document.querySelector('[tabindex="1"]').focus()
  }
  
  e.preventDefault()
  return false
}
```

```html
<section>
  <input placeholder="1" tabindex="1" />
  <input placeholder="2" tabindex="2" />
  <input placeholder="3" tabindex="3" />
  <!-- The onkeydown listener must be on the last focusable input element -->
  <input placeholder="4" tabindex="4" onkeydown="focusFirst(event)" />
</section>
```